# Are Assassins the only Class/Archetype that have the ability to create fake identities?

Tags: dnd-5e, assassin

Are Assassins the only Class/Archetype capable of creating fake identities? I know that the Charlatan Background grants you a False Identity with the proper identification to establish it as real, but as for creating more False Identities it would seem as if the Assassin's Infiltration Expertise ability is the only way to do so, with the cost of 25gp and 7 days of work.

The character I am working on is a Bard with the Charlatan background that uses their Disguise Kit and the Disguise Self spell in order to be assume numerous different identities. These are identities that they would use regularly depending on the occasion. Now, this is usually just a simple "use Deception to convince them you are who you say you are for the moment," but I was wondering if there is a way for my character to establish credibility for these other identities in the same way the False Identity feature is set up?

I don't want to have to put 9 Levels into Rogue just to add credibility to new identities, so I was wondering if their is any way for my character to attempt the same thing the Infiltration Expertise ability allows, however, obviously, not as effectively or efficiently, such as a higher gold cost and more time spent to establish credibility?

Comment: Have you considered having your character hire someone to make fake papers for them? Maybe creating some kind of quid-pro-quo agreement with the person. Have you spoken to your DM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Charlatan Background has the feature:

> FEATURE: FALSE IDENTITY
>   You have created a second identity that includes documentation, established acquaintances, and disguises that allow you to assume that persona.
>   Additionally, you can forge documents including official papers and personal letters, as long as you have seen an example of the kind of document or the handwriting you are trying to copy.

The big difference between that and the Rogue feature, that I can is this:

> [Y]ou can **unfailingly** create false identities for yourself. Vou must spend seven days and 25 gp to establish the history, profession, and affiliations for an identity. 
>   ...
>   Thereafter, if you adopt the new identity as a disguise, **other creatures believe you to be that person until given an obvious reason not to.**

So, Charlatan gives you one identity you can reliably take on without checks.  The Rogue ability allows you to put in time and money to create new identities without checks.

Without those, you'd have to do skill checks for deception, forgery, disguise, etc. each time a situation came up while you're pretending to be someone else.

Say you want to attend a royal ball.  You can put on fancy clothing, perhaps making a skill check.  Now you have to make a skill check to see if you can behave like royalty. If the guy at the door asks to see your patent of nobility, you better hope you already made one and passed the forgery skill check.  You get in, and conversation is going on about who knows the latest gossip about the baron...  Do you even know the baron? Better roll to see if...

All of those rolls goes away with these features. But there is nothing stopping you from trying anyway, and with good luck you might pull it off. And if not, it'll be a lot of fun.

Comment: Thank you for the very in-depth explanation. This makes a lot more sense to me now that I think about it. I guess I was just tripped up on the fact that I believed the ability to be the only way to achieve the creation of fake identities. Being able to accomplish creating more fake identities, even if you have to jump through a lot more hoops and provide many checks, is still a lot better than not being able to do it at all. Thank you again for your thorough explanation and for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple parts to a fake identity: looking and acting the part and having "evidence".

You have the looking the part down. The disguise kit or the *disguise self* spell will take care of it nicely if you know what you have to look like.

In acting the part proficiency or expertise in Deception will be almost necessary and you will find the Actor feat useful (PHB 165).

With "evidence" I mean papers of pedigree or recommendation, signet rings or the like that is not part of the above. With this proficiency with the Forgery kit will help, but special items or materials mighth be needed for more complex items (up to the DM).

So, no, you do not need the assassin ability. It is just a shortcut to all this.

Comment: Indeed.  If the Assassin archetype didn't exist, it would be possible to create a false identity, and adding the archetype doesn't make it any less possible.

Comment: That was my line of thinking, but I hadn't seen anything about creating fake identities properly without that specific ability. Thank you for clearing things up for me greatly!

Answer (score 0):

## Up to the DM

This would be up to the DM. There is no specific rule in DnD 5e that would allow or disallow this. So you should ask the DM if you can or can't, if he says no, you can always use deception checks as you mentioned. If yes, good luck!